# Cannot find -lperl doing a makefile on c++

Tags: c++, perl, makefile

sorry about my bad english...

Well, I'm now to linux, perl and c++, but I have to do some codes for the university and I'm getting some troubles while doing the makefile.

I have a code in perl which is running perfectly. As well, I have a code in C++ that calls perl as a subroutine. Everything is working properly, but when I do the makefile on my computer, it says:

```
sathlervbn Spam C # make clean; make
rm -f *.o
g++  -Wall  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE     -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -L/usr/lib -Wall -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE -    lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt -o main libSpam.a main.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

The problem is that when I run the makefile in my professor's computer, it's works...

Here is the code of makefile:

```
#CC= /usr/bin/g++
CPP = g++
CPPFLAGS = -Wall $(shell perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts)

#LD= /usr/bin/g++
LD = g++

#LFLAGS = -Wall $(shell perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts)

LFLAGS = -Wall -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE - lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt

MAINOBJS = libSpam.a main.o

EMAILS = main

EXECS = $(EMAILS)

#Regra Implicita:
.c.o:
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<

all: emails

emails: $(EMAILS)

main: $(MAINOBJS)
    $(LD) -L/usr/lib $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $(MAINOBJS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: "*I have a code in C++ that calls perl*" => please show us the code, otherwise how are we supposed to know where you went wrong?

Comment: @syam, he's got a linking problem, not a compiling problem.  I don't think the code is relevant.

Comment: @PaulTomblin that was exactly why I didn't put the code.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Sure but still, it could be interesting to see how he calls it in his code. I won't be as harsh as suggesting he didn't install `libperl-dev`, so it has to be something less obvious, right?

Comment: Actually, I just tried compiling a simple C file with -lperl and it told me `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl` - the C file doesn't call any perl code at all.

Comment: @PaulTomblin No problem here using `g++ ... -lperl` with `libperl-dev` 5.14.2-21 on Debian Jessie. Can't reproduce, hence my requests for more details in case I missed something.

Comment: Hmm I just noticed a weird thing in both the makefile and the generated link command line: there seems to be a space between `-` and `lperl`. Maybe this could be it?

Comment: Like I said, I tried it with the correct -lperl and got the same message, until I manually created the symlink between libperl.so.5.14 and libperl.so.

Comment: @Paul Well looks like your symlink thingie solved it for OP, still I can't reproduce on Jessie. Care to `apt-cache policy libperl-dev` and post it here so that we can know which version has a problem (yours) and which version is fixed (mine - 5.14.2-21)?

Comment: I'm not using libperl-dev.  I install perl-base and it installed libperl.so.5.14 but not the symlink.

Comment: @Paul Wait, you're on a Debian-based system and you don't install the `-dev` package to help with development? No wonder why it doesn't link... And more astonishingly, how can you `#include` anything from that lib???

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to install the perl library for C.  If you're on a Debian based system (including Ubuntu) `sudo apt-get install libperl-dev` or something similar may be sufficient, depending on which version of perl you're using.

**Update**: ok, this is a bit strange - I've installed perl-base, and it installed /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14 but it did not make a /usr/lib/libperl.so symlink as you'd expect.  I wonder why not?  If I manually create the symlink with `ln -s /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14 /usr/lib/libperl.so` it links correctly.

**Update the second** I had perl-base installed, but not libperl-dev which gave me `/usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14` but not `/usr/lib/libperl.so`.  I suspect (don't know for sure, but strongly suspect) that the correct answer isn't to manually make the symlink, but to install libperl-dev.

Comment: When I did the apt-get, it said that was already installed. Still the problem of cannot find -lperl.

Comment: @PhaSath see my update.  Try manually creating the link.  You may need to do it as root.

Comment: "*I suspect...*" No need to suspect anything, this is the real problem. Looks like I was wrong in assuming you and OP had installed the `-dev` package... (and as we all know, *assume* makes an as* out of u & me :p) But for my own defence I wasn't sure if you were on a Debian system in the first place. ;) When you want to develop around a library, on Debian systems you **need** the `-dev` package to install both the headers and whatever is necessary to dynamic link the library.

Comment: The answer is *never* to symlink random libraries in system directories.